# Which of these build numbers will tell me what version of SQL Server is installed on a server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

The main Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (64-bit) doesn't contain a version number in `Programs and Features` in Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2:

[image]

To me it almost looks like I have SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM installed on the server since the version numbers match some of the other components listed, notably `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Policies`.

My goal is to install SP2 but when I tried last night I got an error message concerning an unexpected version number.

Is there a way to use sqlcmd to find out what version it is?

Comment: you can have a look at http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can query the database to find out the version via sqlcmd.

The actual SQL you'll want to use is just `SELECT @@VERSION` but to do it via sqlcmd, you can use:

`sqlcmd -S[server] -U[user] -P[password] -q "SELECT @@VERSION"`

Also check the MS [sqlcmd reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) for further info on flags you can use with sqlcmd.